# Make: filtering a list of files containing a given word

Tags: function, makefile, substring, filtering

I've got the following Makefile:

```
INPUT= prefixABC_sample1_suffixXYZ.txt  prefixDEFG_sample1_suffixWXY.txt prefixUGAZ_sample1_suffixAZE.txt \
       prefixHIJK_sample2_suffixUAG.txt prefix9878_sample2_suffixIUHAZD.txt

SAMPLES= sample1 sample2

sample1.out: $(missingfunction sample1,${INPUT})
       echo $^ > $@
```

How can I extract the files from `${INPUT}` containing the word "sample1" ? I known about `$(findstring)` but it returns the key, not the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it using a for loop:

```
sample1 = $(foreach F,$(INPUT),$(if $(findstring sample1,$F),$F))
```